# Writing php errors log to a file with custom data

Tags: php

The following code writes errors in the given file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
```

However, I was wondering if it was possible to log the URL of the page too along with error info?

E.g. if I was on `www.mywebsite.name/calendar.php?id=5&cat=45` and there was some error which shows up in the error_log.txt as `"[22-Jun-2018 05:02:54 Europe/London] PHP Notice: Undefined index: full_date in /var/www/mywebsite/calendar.php on line 180"` I want the above URL to be in the log file too.

I was thinking if I was possible to create own error log writing function which checked if there was a php error, grab it, write it along with additional information ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or whatever)??

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code, you will need to call the [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function. This needs to be made from a point in your code that is called on every request, index.php, might be that point.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // get the called uri
error_log($url);
```

If you only want to log the url on error, then use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) method, to specify a method that will be executed when a error happens, something like this:

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = null, $errline = null){
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // get the called uri
   error_log($url);
   error_log($errno . ' ' . $errstr);
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler");
```

Once again, this code should exist on a script called on every request and you will need to log all the errors that happen.

Comment: I believe that will write all URLs? I would like only write that when there was an error somewhere in any of the scripts?

Comment: I do want to log the error message itself too as I would know what error occurred in which file and what was the URL

Comment: @NoNice yes you're right, to do that you only need to add the error params to the callback function and then log the error with the error_log function

Answer (score 1):

You'll be wanting to look at a custom logging function, or even library if you really want to gain control over how the data is logged.

The simplest, at the most basic level at least, is the built-in PHP function `set_error_handler` — this enables you to overwrite PHP's built-in logger with a function of your own, from that function you would then have to handle the writing to a DB or error.log file.

That can be a lot of manual work sometimes though if you need the log to cover lots of criteria, in which case I suggest two other options:

Monolog is a free library that helps in structuring your error logs :
https://seldaek.github.io/monolog/

It's a little bit more complex to set up, but if you're really interested, definitely look into [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/), it's mostly a paid service, but it logs error's beautifully once you have it all set up.

**Edit** as per my message in the comments below:
You could also bake in try/catch statements, this is a very good practice to start including in the way you write your PHP, it ensures that things that can error get handled and logged in a specific way:

Example:

```
<?php
//create function with an exception
function checkNum($number) {
  if($number>1) {
    throw new Exception("Value must be 1 or below");
  }
  return true;
}

//trigger exception in a "try" block
try {
  checkNum(2);
  //If the exception is thrown, this text will not be shown
  echo 'If you see this, the number is 1 or below';
}

//catch exception
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Further reading on try/catch and exceptions:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: Is there any php function which gives info if there was an error somewhere in the script?

Comment: Sort of yes—but I don't think it's what you after right now. From what I can tell so far my best advice would be to try and start coding with errors and logs built in from the very beginning, you can do this with try/catch statements (I've added one to my answer so you can see).